# Evaluate multiple conditional statements with possible undefined variables

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements, logic, undefined

In Javascript, what would be the best way to evaluate several conditions when taking into consideration variables that could be `undefined`? For instance, I want to evaluate if x > y only if x is NOT undefined (has a value), and if it is undefined, continue to proceed to the next condition.

Something like:

`if(x && x > y && a && a > b && c < d && e > f) ....`

Here I want to see if `x` is defined, and then evaluate if `x` is greater than `y`, then go to evaluate if `a` is defined and evaluate if `a` is greater than `b`, then evaluate if `c` is less than `d` and etc. So here I want it so that if `x` or `a` is undefined CONTINUE to proceed to evaluate `c < d` and `e > f`

```
if(
x // if exists
&& x > y // (if x is defined then evaluate x > y, if not then go to:
&& a // if exists
&& a > b // (if a is defined then evaluate a > b, if not then go to:
&& c < d 
&& e > f
) {
....
}
```

Here if the variables are are undefined then the whole statement is all false... what are some solutions for this that are clean?

Answer (score 0):

You can do `x > y` directly, You need not do `x && x>y`, because they will produce same result and `x>y` syntactically correct as well

```
if(x>y) //when x=undefined and y=10, x>y will be false because undefined>10 is false
        //when x=undefined and y=undefined x>y will be false because undefined>undefined is false
        //when x=10 and y=undefined x>y will be false because 10>undefined is false
```

```
if(x > y && a > b && c < d && e > f)
```

Comment: so it won't evaluate to false immediately and break out of the statement if `x` is undefined? and it'll continue to evaluate `c < d` and `e > f`?

Comment: in `&&` operation wherever `false` is encountered the condition is returned false, so if `x=undefined`, then here `if(x > y && a > b && c < d && e > f)` the first condition will evaluate to false and no further checking will happen

Comment: Right, so here in my case I want it to further check the next conditions

Comment: Then you can use `||` `OR` which will evaluate and check for `truthy` until end. So in `OR` if 1st condition is `true` it will immediately return and no further check will happen, but if 1st condition returns `false` further check will happen until `true` is found and if all conditions exhaust `false` will be returned

Comment: What if I want x > y to evaluate and exit out if it evaluates to false and x is NOT undefined (has value)?

Comment: That will happen with `&&` operation. If say `x=10` and `y=5`, then `x<y` is false and in `&&`, it will exit then only, no further chck will happen

Comment: Please try this `let x=10; let y=5; x<y && console.log(5)`. Here `x<y` will be false and so you will not see `console.log` output. Also try this `let x=5; let y=15; x<y && console.log(5)`, here you will see `console.log` output because `x<y` will evaluates to true hence further checking will happen. Also try `let x=undefined; let y=5; x<y && console.log(5)`, you wont see `console.log` output.